# How do I use the SQL OR operator with a IN SELECT subquery in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This query works fine and returns all the reading elements that contain "がめ":

```
SELECT re.ENTRY_ID, 
       group_concat(re.VALUE, '§') AS read_value, 
       group_concat(re.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, '§') AS furigana_bottom, 
       group_concat(re.FURIGANA_TOP, '§') AS furigana_top, 
       group_concat(gloss.GLOSS_VALUE, '§') AS gloss_value
FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element AS re 
JOIN Jmdict_Gloss AS gloss ON re.ENTRY_ID = gloss.ENTRY_ID
LEFT JOIN Jmdict_Kanji_Element AS ke ON re.ENTRY_ID = ke.ENTRY_ID
WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID 
                      FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element 
                      WHERE VALUE LIKE "がめ")
GROUP BY re.ENTRY_ID
```

But as soon as I try to do this:

```
SELECT re.ENTRY_ID, 
       group_concat(re.VALUE, '§') AS read_value, 
       group_concat(re.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, '§') AS furigana_bottom, 
       group_concat(re.FURIGANA_TOP, '§') AS furigana_top, 
       group_concat(gloss.GLOSS_VALUE, '§') AS gloss_value
FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element AS re
JOIN Jmdict_Gloss AS gloss ON re.ENTRY_ID = gloss.ENTRY_ID
LEFT JOIN Jmdict_Kanji_Element AS ke ON re.ENTRY_ID = ke.ENTRY_ID
WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID
                      FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element
                      WHERE VALUE LIKE "がめ")
   OR gloss.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID
                         FROM Jmdict_Gloss
                         WHERE GLOSS_VALUE LIKE "game")
GROUP BY re.ENTRY_ID
```

It returns all the gloss elements that are like "game" but no reading elements that are like "がめ". How come? I am very much a beginner when it comes to SQL so I could be way off.

Comment: This is really hard to follow. Can you perhaps just replace your code for each case with the output of printing the resultant query?

Comment: @Nick I see, I will try

Comment: @Nick I've done that, do you reckon you could take a look?

Comment: Your query looks fine. Are you sure there's no `がめ` in `read_value`?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes instead of double quotes for text values  i.e. WHERE VALUE LIKE 'がめ' and WHERE GLOSS_VALUE LIKE 'game' ?  You would typically use LIKE 'がめ%' (starts with) or '%がめ' (ends with) or '%がめ%' (anywhere in the column). Using just LIKE 'がめ' is no different to = 'がめ'.

Comment: @MikeT Adding those just includes more results from the `Jmdict_Gloss` table, none from the `Jmdict_Reading_Element` table

Comment: @Nick As the first query returns elements, I am sure.

Comment: @AdenDiamond but the second query returns results too right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need the sub queries as they are just looking inside tables already joined on. Just use a regular where clause:

```
SELECT distinct re.ENTRY_ID, 
       group_concat(re.VALUE, '§') AS read_value, 
       group_concat(re.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, '§') AS furigana_bottom, 
       group_concat(re.FURIGANA_TOP, '§') AS furigana_top, 
       group_concat(gloss.GLOSS_VALUE, '§') AS gloss_value
FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element AS re
JOIN Jmdict_Gloss AS gloss ON re.ENTRY_ID = gloss.ENTRY_ID
LEFT JOIN Jmdict_Kanji_Element AS ke ON re.ENTRY_ID = ke.ENTRY_ID
WHERE (re.VALUE LIKE 'がめ' or OR gloss.GLOSS_VALUE LIKE 'game')
GROUP BY re.ENTRY_ID
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised this got accepted considering it has a typo in it...